# Meteor 1.2 share files between packages

Tags: meteor

Is there a way in Meteor 1.2 to share files between packages?

What I'm trying to do is have a /private/bower_components/* folder which is shared by all packages in the project. This achieves 2 things:

- Eliminates the need to do `bower install` for each package
- Eliminates duplicates if packages share the same libraries

I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions about how I can achieve the above 2 stated goals.

**What I was previously able to do in Meteor 1.1**

In my package.js files I would have:

```
api.addFiles([
    '../../private/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
],'client');
```

However, in Meteor 1.2 this produces the error `Error: Path contains forbidden segment '..'` as discussed [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5252)

**Notes**

I am specifically using bower & not meteor packages because I don't want to include all the files from the libraries. E.g. for bootstrap I use a custom bootstrap.less file and as such I only need the bootstrap.js file from that library.

**The Hard Way**

The only other ways I can think of doing this are by:

- Creating a custom meteor package for each library and reference those from the other packages. This then means I have to maintain a package per dependency which is just horrible.
- Referencing the files directly in the `head` part of my meteor html templates. That then means I need to references files for package dependencies in the project files which will create a spider web of dependencies; which is not ideal.

**[EDIT] Detailed explanation below**

I simplified my question above to highlight my problem; however the following adds clarity to the replies I have received.

**Current structure**

```
private
  └ bower_components
      └ bootstrap
      └ jquery
      └ ...
packages
  └ boilerplate
      └ boilerplate.less
  └ ...
```

I put bower_components under private so that all the files don't automatically get bundled into the meteor build causing unnecessary bloat.

**boilerplate.less**

```
...
@bootstrap-root: "/private/bower_components/bootstrap";
@import "@{bootstrap-root}/less/mixins.less";
@import "@{bootstrap-root}/less/buttons.less";
...
```

This does not work immediately because according to the latest meteor [less package documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/less)** I need to specifically include less files for imports in my package.js file `api.addFiles('x.less', 'client', {isImport: true})` otherwise I get the error:

```
While processing files with less (for target web.browser):
packages/boilerplate/boilerplate.less:6: Unknown import:
/private/bower_components/bootstrap/less/buttons.less
```

...and this leads me to my problem that I need to be able to do this to make it work...

```
...
api.addFiles([
    '../../private/bower_components/bootstrap/less/buttons.less',
],'client',{isImport: true});
...
```

** Yes, there are 2 other methods of including import less files but I don't want to have to run grunt just to change the files installed via bower to include import in the filename or group the less files into an "imports" folder. As I said in Meteor 1.1 this just worked without the headache of grunt - it feels like Meteor is going backwards here.

Comment: What about creating a base package that exports the desired symbols and adding it as a dependency?

Comment: @MasterAM Unfortunately, it is not only js files that need importing; although that was the example I gave. It includes any file you might find in a bower package (js,css,less,etc)

Comment: But those should be included in the build step and bundled. The `less` files should be compiled if the package requires the `less` package, `css` is bundled (and it should not affect the JS), and the JS files are loaded before the requiring package, with the exported symbols available to it. What are you missing when using this method?

Comment: @MasterAM Maybe you can explain your suggestion a bit more, please. I have updated my question with more detail... Currently, I put bower_components in the private folder & reference them from there directly so that only what I need is loaded into the bundle. Either that or add unnecessary complication to include only selected files (grunt with meteor - yuck) or adding all files would create a horribly large bloated bundle. In 1.1 it just worked :(

Comment: My suggestion was pretty much the multi-package one (hard way #1).  I see how this can be annoying, but depending on files being available in a relative path outside of the package dir is not very useful in the context of a meteor package distributability. Have you tried symlinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than a day of trying to get this to work, including:

- Using gulp to pull files out of the `private` directory into the app project root, only to find that I still needed to import them in the package. When this didn't work I tried putting them in an `imports` directory as described in the documentation but that also did not work.
- Unsuccessfully moving the bower_components into the package directory to reference them within the package & then hopefully expose them via imply() in package.js
- Starting down the path of using `api.addFiles('x.less', 'client', {isImport: true})` to import the less files for use in my package. Giving up after realising that I would have to do this for over 50 files because of the number of less imports bootstrap, etc use; and I had no idea what impact this would have in future each time I would do an update to bower packages.
- Using an imports folder so that "import only" less files are automatically imported without needing to use `api.addFiles('x.less', 'client', {isImport: true})`. I could not get this to work as described in the documentation.

I stumbled across the following links:

- [Determine why LESS import from /packages/ directory causes build error on Meteor 1.2 branch #513](https://github.com/apinf/api-umbrella-dashboard/issues/513); which references:
- [What's blocking you from updating to meteor 1.2?](https://github.com/apinf/api-umbrella-dashboard/issues/513)

These links along with the problems I have been having getting this working would lead me to believe that Meteor 1.2 isn't quite ready for dev let alone prod.

For this reason I have decided to downgrade back to Meteor V1.1. Hopefully I can revisit this again in the not-so-distant future.